# how to change youtube short url into embeddable value via form submission to database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i'd like to be able to enter a youtube video's short url into a form input eg;

'http://youtu.be/rAndoMText'

and upon 'submit' perform three functions in the php file that is processing the form:

replace:

`'http://youtu.be/'`

with:

`'<a class='youtube' href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'`

and add:

`'?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">link</a>'`

to the end of the new value

and then submit the final value to the database.

my current php file is below and it's 'logic' is based on my basic knowledge of php and searching for solutions on the internet and i don't expect it to be correct.

it does check out in online syntax checkers though and is sending the other form inputs to the database, just not the one i am trying to modify.

```
<?php

$original_link = $_POST["link"];
$prepender = "<a class='youtube' href=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/\"";
$appender = "?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent\">link</a>";

$modified_link = str_replace ("http://youtu.be/","$prepender","$original_link");

$modified_link . "" . $appender = $final_value;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO data (fieldone, fieldtwo, fieldthree, fieldfour, link)
VALUES
('$_POST[fieldone]','$_POST[fieldtwo]','$_POST[fieldthree]','$_POST[fieldfour]',
'$final_value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
header ('Location: http://return-to-your-website.com');

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

i also tried using this in the 'modified_link' area above but it returned the same results:

```
$modified_link = "";
ob_start (); 
{
echo str_replace ("http://youtu.be/","$prepender","$original_link");
$modified_link = "ob_get_contents ()";
}
ob_end_clean (); 
$modified_link . "" . $appender = $final_value;
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that will give you your desired link:

```
$link_provided_by_user = 'http://youtu.be/rAndoMText';
$random_text = array_pop(explode('/',$link_provided_by_user)); // get the text after the last slash
$link_you_want = '<a class=\'youtube\' href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$random_text.'?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">link</a>';

echo $link_you_want; // ex: <a class='youtube' href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rAndoMText?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">link</a>
```

### Please read about [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: thank you VERY much, the class `'youtube'` needs to be surrounded by single quotes only (and not double quotes).  when i change the above code to contain single quotes, the form gives me an error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING'. when i try to escape the single quotes by putting a backslash before them i get the error 'Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax'.

Comment: the above code should work fine. it means the error is coming elsewhere. I don't know what changes you made in your code since my post but there is also another error in this line: `$modified_link . "" . $appender = $final_value;`

Comment: thank you for your reply, your code is working correctly and submitting the data to the database, thank you.  however it is submitting `a class = "youtube"` (with double quotes around youtube) and i need it to submit `a class = 'youtube'` (with single quotes around youtube).  when i change the double quotes to single quotes i get the error message, and when i try to escape a single quote with a backslash i also get an error.  how can i make youtube just be surrounded by single quotes and not get error messages?  thank you.

Comment: you can use the above code but remember to read about SQL Injections. your fix for that is use [`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/addslashes) or [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)` before inserting it to your database. but please read the link about SQL Injections in my answer so you can improve your code later.

Comment: thank you again for your assistance and for that information. what i found worked was the following modification of your code `$link_you_want = "<a class=\'youtube\' href=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$random_text."?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent\">link</a>";`